# Laravel How to solve Swift Message attach Data error?

Tags: laravel

```
        $pdf = Pdf::loadHTML($html);
        Mail::send(array(), array(), function ($message) use ($fullname, $email, $html, $pdf) {
            $message->to([$email => $fullname])
                ->subject('New Test Mail')
                ->from('noreply@siteaddress.com', 'Test Mail')
                ->setBody($html, 'text/html')
                ->attachData($pdf->output(), "text.pdf");
        });
```

I'm doing the above sending email, but I'm getting an error. I tried all the ways but couldn't find a solution. What could be the cause of this problem?

Error Message:
**Call to undefined method Swift_Message::attachData()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just swap setBody method with attachData like this:

```
 $pdf = Pdf::loadHTML($html);
 Mail::send(array(), array(), function ($message) use ($fullname, $email, $html, $pdf) {
        $message->to([$email => $fullname])
            ->subject('New Test Mail')
            ->from('noreply@siteaddress.com', 'Test Mail')
            ->attachData($pdf->output(), "text.pdf")
            ->setBody($html, 'text/html');
    });
```

It worked for me.